# Simple JQuery Sliding Effect Gets Out of Sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this simple `JQuery` code that will slide the content from one `div` to the next. However after the browser being open for some time, eventually, it will get off sync and all of them start flying across the screen at the same time, and end up on top of each other. Any ideas what is wrong on my code?

```js
$(function() {
  function sp18() {
    div = $('#container .box.selected');

    $(div).animate({
      left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
      $(div).css('left', '150%').removeClass("selected");
      $(div).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(div).next().animate({
      left: '0'
    }, 500).addClass("selected");

    setTimeout(sp18, 200);
  }

  setTimeout(sp18, 100);
});
```

```css
#container {
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 38px;
  position: relative;
}

#container .box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 150%;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#container .box span {
  color: #555
}

#container .box.selected {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box selected">slide 1</div>
  <div class="box">slide 2</div>
  <div class="box">slide 3</div>
  <div class="box">slide 4</div>
</div>
```

Occasionally the screen will look like this when they are out of sync:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to add the `setTimeout()` inside the latest [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) `complete()` callback function. So, this way you wait for the latest animation to finish before calling again the `sp18` function, otherwise, if you don't wait an animation to finish before starting a new one, eventually you will get out of sync:

```js
function sp18()
{
    let div = $('#container .box.selected');

    $(div).animate({left:'-50%'}, 500, function()
    {
        $(div).css('left', '150%').removeClass("selected");
        $(div).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(div).next().animate({left:'0'}, 500, function()
    {
        setTimeout(sp18, 250);

    }).addClass("selected");
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout(sp18, 1000);
});
```

```css
#container {
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  overflow: hidden;  
  line-height:38px;
  position: relative;
}

#container .box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 150%;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height:38px;
  font-size:13px;
}

#container .box span {
  color:#555
}

#container .box.selected {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"> 
  <div class="box selected">slide 1</div>
  <div class="box">slide 2</div>
  <div class="box">slide 3</div>
  <div class="box">slide 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `});` at the end of your javascript, removing which makes the code work as expected.

Alternatively you can put everything inside `$(document).ready()` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function sp18() {
    div = $("#container .box.selected");
    $(div).animate({left: "-50%"}, 500, function() {
      $(div).css("left", "150%").removeClass("selected");
      $(div).appendTo("#container");
    });

    $(div).next().animate({left: "0"}, 500).addClass("selected");
    setTimeout(sp18, 8000);
  }

  setTimeout(sp18, 3000);
});
```

The codepen demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVXJBz

Comment: I will say it again (and was not me who downvote this), the problem is not the extra `});` caused, maybe, by a **copy/paste** mistake of the OP. If you decrease the delay of `8000` used on `setTimeout()` method to `100` or something low, you will note the out of sync problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it wasn't answering the question I had.  The question wasn't saying the code wasn't working.  But that it was the sync issue.